# How do I make a battery voltage indicator using the battery being tested?

Tags: batteries, test

I am trying to make a circuit that will test if a 5V battery is under 5V, with the testing circuit running off the battery being tested.

I have seen other answers to this question, however they rely on separate power sources to power the circuit. I am looking for a system similar to those found in flashlights or smoke alarms, telling you to replace the battery.

Any help would be great :)

Comment: You asked this a few days ago, and I recommended a voltage monitor chip - and got voted down for it. Now, here we are again. Did you change your mind? Here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/494796/how-do-i-test-the-voltage-of-a-battery-without-a-multimeter-analogue-component

Comment: What do you mean have I changed my mind? I upvote every person who takes time to answer my question, you included. Thank you for you contribution.

Comment: I didn't say *you* voted me down, and thank you for your upvote. Someone *did* though. Why? The Q said 'analogue components'. The fact that *now* you accept a chip as an answer is where 'changed your mind' comes from.

Comment: Meanwhile, at that other Q, someone (not you) took it upon themselves to vote down my answer which is the same (use a chip) to the (accepted) answer here. Ultimately it has nothing to do with you, or your question. It's a problem with SE and... shall we say... with a certain mindset that some answerers adopt. I think outside the box, and don't let the question constrain my thinking into an XY problem. And sometimes I get downvoted for it.

Comment: I'm sorry if I confused you. I posted this question because I figured analogue wasn't going to cut it for me in this application. You suggested an IC, and I figured that was probably going to be easier to implement than analogue, so I asked this question, and got more IC ideas. I'm still considering your contribution, and it's probably what I'm going to use in my project, so thank you :)

Comment: I wasn't confused at all. Seeing your thinking on the topic progress is a *good* thing. You moved out of the 'analogue' box since that Q.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would consider using a [MAX931](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX931-MAX934.pdf) low-power comparator with an in-built voltage reference that is accurate to within 1% of 1.182 volts : -

[image]

V+ and Vin can connect to the battery and the two resistors (use high values to avoid excessive battery current) set the point at which the output goes low when the battery voltage drops below the required set-point.

The chip works from 2.5 volts to 11 volts so 5 volts is fine.

Choose the resistor divider so that the low threshold for the battery (say 4 volts) produces 1.18 volts at IN+.

What you drive with the output is up for grabs but, a simple scheme might be to illuminate a low power LED when the output switches low thus indicating that the battery has dropped below 4 volts (or whatever value you think is right).

The output stage can easily drive 10 mA into an LED and series resistor tied up to the battery supply. Or maybe you use the logic low output to trigger a low frequency oscillator that pulses the LED on for 0.5 seconds every (say) 20 seconds.

Or maybe you just drive a low power LED when the battery voltage is good. No LED illumination means battery bad.

Comment: I just stumbled upon this question. But what is the pin for the set-point and the voltage to be monitored? I think Vin and resistors sets the threshold voltage, but where does the input voltage to be monitored  couple to?

Comment: I said this above: "V+ and Vin can connect to the battery". The internal voltage reference is the set point.

Comment: @hacktastical who and what post are you referring to?

Comment: @hacktastical yeah it looks pretty similar but I didn't downvote your answer so I guess you are referring to the OP of this question?

Comment: Wait... sorry. The comments were meant for the OP. I moved them there.